# Loading data from a Google Persistent Disk into BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

What's the recommended way of loading data into BigQuery that is currently located in a Google Persistent Disk? Are there any special tools or best practises for this particular use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy to GCS (Google Cloud Storage), point BigQuery to load from GCS.

There's no current direct connection between a persistent disk and BigQuery. You could send the data straight to BigQuery with the bq CLI, but makes everything slower if you ever need to retry.